# Prove that the ellipsoid $x^T W x \leq 1$ is invariant under $f (x) = A x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariance

> Given matrix $W \succ 0 $ and a set $\mathcal{Z} := \{z \mid z^T W z \leq 1\}$, prove that if $Az \in \mathcal{Z}$ and $z \in\mathcal{Z}$, then the following inequality holds
>
> $$ A^T W A - W \preceq 0$$

Comment: _Hint_: $z^TA^TWAz - z^TWz = z^T(A^TWA - W)z$.

Comment: @FightingWLC you probably mean "Prove that if $Az \in \mathcal{Z}$ for all $z \in \mathcal{Z}$, right?

Comment: @ErikJoensson : Yes. I thought about the definition of a negative semidefinite matrix. But I get stuck. Do you please give more hints?

Comment: This is closely related to the **Discrete Lyapunov Equation** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation )

Comment: @ Malkoun: You are right. I mean that this inequality is only true for limited vectors $z$.

Comment: another hint: use a $W$-orthonormal basis of your vector space.

Comment: @Malkoun: I am sorry, but I still do not see. I just see that $Az$ and $z$ belong to $\mathcal{Z}$, so that $z^T A^T W A z \leq 1$ and $z^T Wz \leq 1$

Comment: @FightingWLC take a vector $z$ such that $z^TWz = 1$. Multiply the left-hand side by $z^T$ from the left and by $z$ from the right. Similar to a previous hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Begin by showing that if $z$ is a vector such that $z^TWz = 1$, then we know that
$$
z^T(A^TWA - W)z \leq 0
$$
Using the fact that $W$ is invertible, conclude that $z^TWz \leq 0$ for *every* $z$, so that $A^TWA - W$ is negative definite by definition.